# error in callback function value retrieval gurobi python getvars()

Tags: python, callback, gurobi

I have a variable _vars[0] in my gurobi(python) code. I am able to get the attribute _vars[0].X after completing the optimisation. but when I do the same operation inside my callback function, I get this error"Exception AttributeError: AttributeError('',) in 'gurobipy.callbackstub' ignored"

it works if I do,

```
m.optimize(mycallback)
_vars = m.getVars()
print _vars[0].X
```

but if I do

```
def mycallback(m, where): 
     _vars =  m.getVars()
     a =  _vars[0].X
     print (a)
```

I get the error

```
"Exception AttributeError: AttributeError('',) in 'gurobipy.callbackstub' ignored"
```

Is there any way that I can get the value of this attribute inside the callback function?

Comment: Just to clarify: Assuming you're facing a MIP. Do you want the values of each new found incumbent solution in the MIP or just the values of the optimal solution after the optimization terminated?

Comment: try to use `for loop` on `_vars` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
    from gurobipy import *

    model = Model("test")
    var1 = model.addVar(ub=2.0, name="x")
    var2 = model.addVar(ub=2.0, name="y")

    def mycallback(model, where):
        vars = model.getVars()
        for v in vars:
            print(v.VarName)

   model.optimize(mycallback(model, GRB.Callback.MIP))
```